# Map physical address to virtual in kernel space for simulated system

Tags: c, linux, kernel, mmap, qemu

I'm doing some work with MARSSx86, a QEMU-based x86 simulator. I'm trying to send some data between the guest OS and the simulator. Normally, this is handled by using a library provided by the developer that writes to a special area in memory reserved for this sort of communication. However, I'm trying to do this operation in kernel space, and the library depends on doing an mmap, which obviously won't work. As I understand it, all I need to do is get access to a known physical address and write some data there.

I'm very unfamiliar with memory operations, especially in the kernel, but I feel like this should be straightforward. I believe I could just use ioremap, but it doesn't provide a usable virtual address as I understand it, which the code as it's implemented requires. To make things clearer, here's the code that sets up the mapping:

```
#define bits(x, i, l) (((x) >> (i)) & bitmask(l))
#define LO32(x) (W32)((x) & 0xffffffffLL)
#define bitmask(l) (((l) == 64) ? (W64)(-1LL) : ((1LL << (l))-1LL))

static int ptlsim_check_status __attribute__((common)) = 0;
static W64 supported_ptlcall_methods __attribute__((common)) = 0;
static int selected_ptlcall_method __attribute__((common)) = -1;
static W64 ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr __attribute__((common)) = 0;
static W64* ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr __attribute__((common)) = NULL;
static W16 ptlcall_io_port __attribute__((common)) = 0;

static int ptlsim_ptlcall_init() {
  W32 rax = PTLSIM_CPUID_MAGIC;
  W32 rbx = 0;
  W32 rcx = 0;
  W32 rdx = 0;
  int ptlcall_mmio_page_offset;
  static const char* mmap_filename = "/dev/mem";

  // a.k.a. cpuid(PTLSIM_CPUID_MAGIC, rax, rbx, rcx, rdx);
  asm volatile("cpuid" : "+a" (rax), "+b" (rbx), "+c" (rcx), "+d" (rdx) : : "memory");

  if (rax != PTLSIM_CPUID_FOUND) {
    ptlsim_check_status = -1;
    return 0;
  }

  supported_ptlcall_methods = rbx;
  ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr = (bits(rdx, 0, 16) << 32) | LO32(rcx);
  ptlcall_mmio_page_offset = (ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr & 0xfff);
  ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr &= ~0xfff;
  ptlcall_io_port = bits(rdx, 16, 16);

  if (supported_ptlcall_methods & PTLCALL_METHOD_MMIO) {
    // We use O_SYNC to guarantee uncached accesses:
    int fd = open(mmap_filename, O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE|O_SYNC, 0);

    if (fd < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ptlsim_ptlcall_init: cannot open %s for MMIO to physaddr %p (%s)\n",
      mmap_filename, (void*)ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr, strerror(errno));
      supported_ptlcall_methods &= ~PTLCALL_METHOD_MMIO;
      ptlsim_check_status = -2;
      return 0;
    }

    ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr = (W64*)mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr);

    if (((int)(Waddr)ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr) == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ptlsim_ptlcall_init: cannot mmap %s (fd %d) for MMIO to physaddr %p (%s)\n", mmap_filename, fd, (void*)ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr, strerror(errno));
      supported_ptlcall_methods &= ~PTLCALL_METHOD_MMIO;
      ptlsim_check_status = -3;
      close(fd);
      return 0;
    }

    // Adjust the pointer to the actual trigger word within the page (usually always offset 0)
    ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr = (W64*)(((Waddr)ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr) + ptlcall_mmio_page_offset);

    close(fd);

    selected_ptlcall_method = PTLCALL_METHOD_MMIO;
    fprintf(stderr, "ptlsim_ptlcall_init: mapped PTLcall MMIO page at phys %p, virt %p\n", (void*)ptlcall_mmio_page_physaddr, (void*)ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr);
  }

  ptlsim_check_status = +1;

  return 1;
}
```

And here's the code that does the actual communication once it's set up (I'm obviously leaving a lot out here for brevity, but if something important is missing let me know and I can edit it in):

```
static inline W64 ptlcall_single(const char* command, int flush) {
  struct  PTLsimCommandDescriptor desc;
  desc.command = (W64)command;
  desc.length = strlen(command);

  return ptlcall(PTLCALL_ENQUEUE, (W64)&desc, 1, flush, 0, 0, 0);
}

static inline W64 ptlcall(W64 op, W64 arg1, W64 arg2, W64 arg3, W64 arg4, W64 arg5, W64 arg6) 
{
  if (!is_running_under_ptlsim())
    return (W64)(-ENOSYS);

  if (selected_ptlcall_method == PTLCALL_METHOD_MMIO) {
    return do_ptlcall_mmio(op, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
  } else
    return (W64)(-ENOSYS);
}

static inline W64 do_ptlcall_mmio(W64 callid, W64 arg1, W64 arg2, W64 arg3, W64 arg4, W64 arg5, W64 arg6)
{
  W64 rc;
  asm volatile ("movq %[arg4],%%r10\n"
            "movq %[arg5],%%r8\n"
            "movq %[arg6],%%r9\n"
            "mfence\n"
            "smsw %[target]\n"
            : "=a" (rc),
              [target] "=m" (*ptlcall_mmio_page_virtaddr)
            : [callid] "a" (callid),
              [arg1] "D" ((W64)(arg1)),
              [arg2] "S" ((W64)(arg2)),
              [arg3] "d" ((W64)(arg3)),
              [arg4] "g" ((W64)(arg4)),
              [arg5] "g" ((W64)(arg5)),
              [arg6] "g" ((W64)(arg6))
            : "r11","rcx","memory" ,"r8", "r10", "r9");
  return rc;
}
```

Basically, I want to put all of this code in the kernel, then rewrite the memory operations in the first chunk of code so that the second chunk of code can run unmodified. From what I've found I feel like remap_pfn_range may be the function I need, but I can't figure out how to use it in this context. I realize this is a lot, so any pointers at all are appreciated even if they don't answer the entire question.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the address returned by ioremap would be unusable?